# Materail UI x React: Autocomplete closes when an item tries to show Popover

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to have a customized Autocomplete and each item has a more icon when you hover a mouse pointer.

When you click the icon, it supposes to bring Popover up, but instead it closes the Autocomplete list.

[image]

The image above, I'm hovering a pointer on the icon, and when I clicked it, it closed the list.

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { TextField, Paper } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Autocomplete, useAutocomplete } from "@material-ui/lab";
import Item from "./Item";

const App = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

  const countries = [
    { code: "US", label: "USA", phone: "1" },
    { code: "HU", label: "Hungary ", phone: "2" },
    { code: "IT", label: "Italy ", phone: "3" }
  ];

  const openMultipleOptionSearch = (event) => {
    setIsOpen(true);
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const {
    getRootProps,
    getInputLabelProps,
    getInputProps,
    getListboxProps,
    getOptionProps,
    groupedOptions
  } = useAutocomplete({
    id: "use-autocomplete-demo",
    options: countries,
    getOptionLabel: (option) => option.label,
    disableCloseOnSelect: true
  });

  return (
    <div {...getRootProps()}>
      <input {...getInputProps()} />
      <Paper>
        {groupedOptions.length > 0 &&
          groupedOptions.map((option, index) => (
            <Item key={index} text={option.label} onClose={() => {}} />
          ))}
        {groupedOptions.length === 0 && <p>No match.</p>}
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Item.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import MoreHoriz from "@material-ui/icons/MoreHoriz";
import { Box, Typography, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import Popup from "./Popup";

const Item = (prop) => {
  const [onMouseOver, setOnMouseOver] = useState(false);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

  const openDeleteItem = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    setIsOpen(true);
  };

  const closeDeleteItem = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    setIsOpen(false);
    setOnMouseOver(false);
    prop.onClose();
  };

  return (
    <Box
      onMouseOver={() => setOnMouseOver(true)}
      onMouseOut={() => isOpen || setOnMouseOver(false)}
    >
      <div className="item-container">
        <Typography variant="body1">{prop.text}</Typography>
      </div>
      <Button
        style={{ display: onMouseOver ? "" : "none" }}
        onClick={openDeleteItem}
      >
        <MoreHoriz />
      </Button>
      <Popup
        isOpen={isOpen}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={() => closeDeleteItem()}
      />
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

Popup.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Popover } from '@material-ui/core';

const Popup = (prop) => {
  return (
    <Popover
      id={prop.isOpen ? 'simple-popover' : undefined}
      open={prop.isOpen}
      anchorEl={prop.anchorEl}
      onClose={() => prop.onClose()}
    >
      Popup content
    </Popover>
  );
};


export default Popup;
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Why don't you use the `Autocomplete` component from MUI?

Answer (score 0):

I think your autocomplete popup is getting blurred when you click on more button, so it looses focus and closes the dropdown itself.

this might help you - [OnBlur closing react component if clicked inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63953850/onblur-closing-react-component-if-clicked-inside)

Comment: I used Popper instead and it worked. I looked into onBlur but it didn't change the result.